# Windows Phone 8 in VS2015

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015

I need to write Windows Phone background tracking application. As I started to read there is no good option to write it in Windows Phone 8.1. Does someone know how to create Windows Phone 8 in Visual Studio 2015. Every template I can choose is for Windows Phone 8.1.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install the SDK 8.0 :
https://www.microsoft.com/fr-fr/download/details.aspx?id=35471

And just for information :

- You won't have the ability to debug with a Windows phone 8.0. Today, only the windows phone 8.1 are unlockable for development.
- My guess is you want dev a location tracking application as describe in this link :
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/jj247548(v=vs.105).aspx
- Keep in mind there is a 4 hours limitations.
- The user can exit the application and there are no more geolocation afterwards.

Hope it fits your needs

Comment: Your link gives package with Visual Studio 2012, but author asked you about Visual Studion 2015 support for Phone 8. I have the same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40816674/can-i-use-visual-studio-2015-for-creating-windows-phone-8-applications).