# Can I use Visual Studio 2015 for creating Windows Phone 8 applications?

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015

I have Visual Studio 2015 Community edition installed with Windows Desktop development tools (languag - C++). Can I use it for creating Windows Phone 8 application with C++ language (especially with C++11/14 standard)? Which SDK\tools I have to install for this task or may be all required instruments are in Visual Studio 2015 Community package alredy?

Thank you for help.

P.S.: The ["Visual Studio 2015 Platform Targeting and Compatibility"](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/productinfo/vs2015-compatibility-vs#visual-studio-2015-support-for-windows-universal-windows-store-and-windows-phone-app-development) article, in the section "*Visual Studio 2015 Support for Windows Universal, Windows Store, and Windows Phone App Development*", says that Windows Phone 8 apps are supported by the Visual Studio 2015 but with footnotes "*Supports migration of Windows Phone 8 projects to Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1.*". So, I can't understand, does Visual Studio 2015 support the whole development cycle for Windows Phone 8 app or only migration to the Windows Phone 8.1?

UPDATE: I mean the Windows Runtime applications for Windows Phone 8 platform.

Comment: It is more complicated than "C++" and "Windows Phone 8". You have to decide which *runtime environment* you want to use. You can write *native* Win32 applications for Windows Phone (or any other implementation of Win32) using the VS for Windows Desktop development tools. You can also develop Universal apps, that target the Windows Runtime. But none of this matters if you're using Visual Studio *Community*; that doesn't come in editions. Only Express comes in editions, like Windows Desktop and Web.

Comment: @CodyGray, No, I don't want to write the *native Win32* (desktop) or *native UWP* (Win10 platforms). I want to create Phone 8 RT application using C++ language (as I know this is some kind of the native app with metadata supporting).

Comment: I suppose it depends on the edition of VS you use.  The retail edition exposes it by default as Visual C++ > Windows > Install Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 Tools.  Which, presumably, after going through the install produce adds new project templates.  Do keep in mind that the Phone ecosystem is not one with many happy stories, the platform has largely failed in spite of billions of dollars thrown at it.  The UWP edition appears to be terminally stuck in beta and market share has dropped to 0.7% last May.

Comment: @HansPassant, Yes, I know about the UWP market share. And I'm sad about this, because UWP technically is a successful.

Comment: @23W, Do you want to create Windows Runtime project or Windows Silverlight project using C++ language? If you want to create windows Runtime project, I think you should create Windows phone 8.1 application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, you need to download windows phone 8/8.1 sdk from microsoft website
https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35471 or from somewhere which provide standalone installer for this.
after this, just open up visual studio go to c++ the expand windows > windows phone

Comment: standalon link go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=257234&clcid=0x409‎

Comment: As I see, this SDK contains VS2012 Express. Does this mean that I am limited with v110(VS2012) toolset and can't to use all features of C++11\14 ?

Comment: Yes i am using vs2015 enterprise with windows phone 8/8.1 sdk because of third we are unable to use extra toolkit. But you still you will able to most of tools, alternatively you can install wp8/8.1 sdk by opening your vs setup and click on modify and then check all function you required inc. Wp8 sdk